# VueJS: Fixing component order in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I've been having some trouble recently with the order of Vue components in Bootstrap. I'm trying to generate some Bootstrap collapsible content in Vue here's the code so far:

HTML

```html
<div class="col-sm main-content" id="main-content">
    <p>
        <main-section-button v-for="item in sections"
                             v-bind:section="item"
                             v-bind:data-target="'#section-' + item.text"
                             v-bind:aria-controls="'section-' + item.text">
        </main-section-button>
    </p>
    <main-section v-for="item in sections"
                  v-bind:id="'section-' + item.text">
    </main-section>
</div>
```

VueJS

```js
Vue.component("main-section-button", {
    props: ["section"],
    template: String.raw`<button class="btn btn-block btn-dark" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">{{ section.text }}</button>`
});

Vue.component("main-section", {
    props: ["section"],
    template: String.raw`<div class="collapse"><div class="card card-body"><p>Hello, World!</p></div></div></div>`
});


let app = new Vue({
    el: '#main-content',
    data: {
        sections: [
            { id: 0, text: "example1"},
            { id: 0, text: "example2"}
        ]
    }
});
```

I have tried to make just one component for `main-section` and `main-section-button`, but that did not work because of the requirement to pass an `id` to the card (collapsible content), and a `data-target` to the button that collapses and expands the content.

### Current Result

[image: Current Result]

### Required Result

[image: Required Result]

Is it possible to create a component so that the section content is always below the section button.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have two options to achieve this:

1. Create a new component that takes the items and displays both components as you wish.
2. Do not iterate over the components, instead use a `<div>` around both components or a non-rendered `<template>` like this:

```
<div class="col-sm main-content" id="main-content">
    <template v-for="item in sections">
        <p>
            <main-section-button 
                v-bind:section="item"
                v-bind:data-target="'#section-' + item.text"
                v-bind:aria-controls="'section-' + item.text">
            </main-section-button>
        </p>
        <main-section
            v-bind:id="'section-' + item.text">
        </main-section>
    </template>
</div>
```